# Using Soot programmatically to analyze .java source files

Tags: code-analysis, static-code-analysis, soot, program-slicing

I have just started playing around with Soot in order to analyze .java files programmatically. From what I've read, Soot seems to be a very powerful tool for source code analysis but most of the material I found online talks about using it as a command-line tool.

I need to programmatically load classes from .java files in a given directory, construct a Program Dependence Graph (PDG) and do some Program Slicing. I am still not sure if Soot offers slicing but I can implement that myself once I have the PDG.

To get started, I tried using the code below:

```
Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
Options.v().set_soot_classpath("...");

SootClass c = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("MyClass");
c.setApplicationClass();

CHATransformer.v().transform();
CallGraph cg = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
```

However, it does not work. It gets stuck at the `loadClassAndSupport` call for a few seconds and then my program just exists abruptly, without giving any exception or anything.

If anyone has tried to use Soot programmatically, are there any other options that I need to set? Or can you point me to a tutorial where they set up Soot **programmatically** from scratch?

Comment: Did you succed? If yes, how?

Comment: I ended up using Wala (http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to do the source code analysis that I needed. I found that it was a bit easier to use and has more documentation online.

Comment: @Rizkallah would be curious to know whether wala was enough for doing program slicing. Also, your implementation is opensource?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use loadClassAndSupport. Insert a "Scene transformer" instead. Slicing can be achieved by using the FlowDroid extension to Soot. It supports slicing of both Android and Java code.